# Discontinuities and their locations

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

So we were given a problem that states

Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the greatest integer $\leq x and let (x) = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the fractional part of x. Identify the location and type of discontinuities for each of the functions [x] and (x).

I understand that the fractional part of function (x) would be something like $(\pi)$ = .14159.....

My dilemma is however finding the areas in which this is discontinuous. I'm thinking something along the lines of a step wise function but I'm still not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens to these functions at integer values. Are they continuous at those points? What about between those points?

Comment: I would assume that the integer values decrease yet remain continuous. I'm still not 100% sure on this question

Comment: What is the value of $\lfloor 6 \rfloor$? What about $\lfloor 5.9 \rfloor$? $\lfloor 5.99 \rfloor$? $\lfloor 5.999999999 \rfloor$? $\lfloor \lim_{x\to 6^-} \rfloor$?

Comment: got it thanks! I should've drew out a graph from the get go. It made the problem a lot easier to understand